# Esperar uma função executar para realizar a próxima

Tags: javascript, promises, callback

Estou fazendo um Script em JS porém estou com uma pequena dificuldade.

Queria fazer com que minha função Loop() fosse novamente chamada somente quando a minha Função FaTown() já tivesse sido totalmente executada, hoje quando executo o Script a função Loop() é chamada antes da função FaTown() ser executada por completo

Segue o trecho do código

```js
(function loop() {
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (minutoMax - minutoMin)) + minutoMin;
  console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
  setTimeout(function() {
    FaTown();
    loop();
  }, rand);
}());
```

```js
function FaTown() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    uw.FarmTown.openFarm();
    setTimeout(function() {
      try {
        $('.checkbox.selcionar_tudo').click();
      } catch (e) {
        //
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("pegar_button").click()
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.btn_confirmar_sim').click();
          setTimeout(function() {
            var janelas = GPWindowMgr.getOpenedClosableWindows();
            for (var i = 0; i < janelas.length; i++) {
              if (janelas[i].type === 589) {
                janelas[i].close();
                break;
              }
            }
          }, timeOpen)
        }, time1)
      }, time2)
    }, time3)
  }, time4)
}
```

Comment: Não entendi nada. Explique melhor e com mais detalhes o que voce já tentou.

Comment: Estou fazendo o edit da pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que você está simulando um intervalo entre um clique e outro com esses `setTimeout`.

Você pode obter o mesmo resultado usando `await` dentro de uma função assíncrona, e como resultado você também poderia utilizar o `await` para esperar pela resolução da função antes de roda-la novamente:

```js
async function sleep(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

async function FaTown() {
    await sleep(time4);
    uw.FarmTown.openFarm();

    await sleep(time3);
    const checkbox = $('.checkbox.selcionar_tudo');
    if (checkbox) checkbox.click();

    await sleep(time2);
    document.getElementById('pegar_button').click();

    await sleep(time1);
    $('.btn_confirmar_sim').click();

    await sleep(timeOpen);
    const janelas = GPWindowMgr.getOpenedClosableWindows();
    for (let i = 0; i < janelas.length; i++) {
        if (janelas[i].type === 589) {
            janelas[i].close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

(async function loop() {
    const rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (minutoMax - minutoMin)) + minutoMin;
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
    await sleep(rand);

    await FaTown();
    loop();
})();
```

Mas isso é uma sugestão, se você pretende continuar com o `setTimeout` pode utilizar uma função de callback para a `FaTown` invocar após terminar de executar, no caso, essa função seria o próprio `loop`:

```
function FaTown(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        uw.FarmTown.openFarm();
        setTimeout(function () {
            try {
                $('.checkbox.selcionar_tudo').click();
            } catch (e) {
                //
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("pegar_button").click()
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.btn_confirmar_sim').click();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var janelas = GPWindowMgr.getOpenedClosableWindows();
                        for (var i = 0; i < janelas.length; i++) {
                            if (janelas[i].type === 589) {
                                janelas[i].close();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        callback();
                    }, timeOpen)
                }, time1)
            }, time2)
        }, time3)
    }, time4)
}

(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (minutoMax - minutoMin)) + minutoMin;
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
    setTimeout(function () {
        FaTown(loop);
    }, rand);
}());
```

[Mais sobre async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) e [função callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).